# Support of bivariate transform

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**The question:**

How do you determine the support, $S_{y_1,y_2}$, of a transformed joint probability density function given the support $S_{x_1,x_2}$, especially when using continuous variables?

**The problem statement:**

Given the joint pdf

$$ f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)=\begin{cases} 
      2e^{-x_1-x_2} & 0\lt x_1 \lt x_2 \lt \infty\\
      0 & else 
   \end{cases}
$$

Find the joint pdf for $Y_1 = 2X_1$ and $Y_2=X_2-X_1$

**My work:**

Working out the expression for the joint pdf of $Y_1,Y_2$ with the formula gave:

$$f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)= \begin{cases}
     e^{-y_2} & (y_1,y_2)\in S_{y_1,y_2}\\
     0 & else 
\end{cases}
$$

I am familiar with the "conditional support method" where I find the support of  $Y_1$, fix a value in that support and then find $Y_{2}$ that satisfies $(y_1,y_2)=(u_1(x_1,x_2),u_2(x_1,x_2))$ for $(x_1,x_2)\in S_{x_1,x_2}$

This seemed pretty easy when I was dealing with the last problem which involved discreet random variables. I am unsure of how to apply it in this situation.

Comment: Have you heard of the change of variable formula? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables

Comment: @Kore-N, Yes, I think so. Isn't that the formula used to find the joint pdf of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$? I already applied that to my problem, but that formula does not tell you how to determine the support, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Express $0 < x_1 < x_2$ as two inequalities: $0 < x_1$ and $x_1 < x_2$ (both must hold simultaneously). The first is equivalent to $0 < y_1$ and the second is equivalent to $0 < x_2 - x_1$, which is the same as $0 < y_2$. So, the support expressed in terms of $y_1$ and $y_2$ is: $y_1 > 0$ and $y_2 > 0$.

Comment: @Bungo I was told that finding the supports of $y_1$ and $y_2$ separately and then mashing them together as the overall support is a dangerous thing to do. My teacher referred to this as the "Cartesian product method" and said to avoid it. Isn't that what you did?

Comment: @rocksNwaves No, I showed that the support of the joint pdf works out to be $\{(y_1, y_2) \in \mathbb R^2 : y_1 > 0 \text{ and } y_2 > 0\}$, which coincidentally is the Cartesian product of $\{y_1 \in \mathbb R : y_1 > 0\}$ and $\{y_2 \in \mathbb R : y_2 > 0\}$, but I didn't assume that at the outset.